# aws-sdk Signed URL Failing on Heroku during production but works in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

I have my code written below, and all of this generates my signed URL perfectly fine when on development and the files that I want to get and upload locally work.

```
const S3 = require("aws-sdk/clients/s3");
const fs = require("fs");

const s3 = new S3({
    region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    signatureVersion: "v2",
});

const uploadFile = (file, id, directory) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
    const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Body: fileStream,
        Key: directory + id,
        MimeType: file.mimetype,
    };
    return s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
};

exports.uploadFile = uploadFile;

const deleteFile = (id, directory) => {
    const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: directory + id,
    };
    return s3.deleteObject(uploadParams).promise();
};

exports.deleteFile = deleteFile;

const getFileStream = ({ key }) => {
    if (key) {
        const downloadParams = {
            Key: key,
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        };
        return s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream();
    }
};

exports.getFileStream = getFileStream;

function generatePreSignedPutUrl({ key, operation }) {
    var params = { Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME, Key: key, Expires: 60 };
    let x = s3.getSignedUrl(operation, params);
    return x;
}

exports.generatePreSignedPutUrl = generatePreSignedPutUrl;
```

These are the requests I make from the client

```
const getSignedURL = async ({ key, operation }) =>
    client.post(`${endpoint}/get-signed-url`, { key, operation });


const result = await getSignedURL({
        key: directory + "/" + key,
        operation: "getObject",
    });
    let url = result.data.data.url;
    console.log({ url });
```

and this is the route on my server.

```
router.post("/get-signed-url", requireKey, async (req, res) => {
    const { key, operation } = req.body;
    try {
        console.log({ b: req.body });
        let url = generatePreSignedPutUrl({ key, operation });
        console.log({ url });
        res.json({ success: true, data: { url } });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log({ e });
        res.status(400).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
});
```

I followed all of S3's documentation to get this set up and I am trying to make sure all files can be downloaded and uploaded securely from my application. Does anyone know how I can get this to work in production when the server is hosted in Heroku and the client is a nextjs site?

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by "failing"? Are you getting error messages? What do they say?

Comment: Have you made sure to set the various `AWS_` config vars on Heroku? Are you entirely sure you've used the right values? they don't include newlines or anything weird like that?

Comment: @Chris The failure log from AWS is that the incorrect signature is being sent. I did a test to see if the AWS_ variables were correct and they were exactly as used in development. I'm not sure if the issue has to do with my policies in S3 but I did set up an IAM user policy that gives is getObject, putObject, and deleteObject access

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using signature v2?